# How can I read a high frequency PWM falling edge with Arduino interrupts?

Tags: arduino, sensor, pwm, electromagnetism, hall-effect

My project is about a Magnetic Levitator. I control the electromagnet with a high frequency PWM signal which I use on the MOSFET gate to give to it enough current.

The thing is that I use a linear Hall effect sensor to detect the object levitating, which is a ball with a neodymium magnet attached to it.

So, I need to read the proximity of the object, i.e., the magnetic field from the neodymium permanent magnet, ignoring the field of the electromagnet.

I thought I could read it during the Low state on the PWM signal, which I vary from 10% to 50% duty cycle, using Arduino Interrupts.

I am not sure if this will work due to high frequency of the PWM signal (up to 100kHz).

Any ideas or alternatives?  Thanks!!!

Comment: I'd start by making sure the frequency response of your Hall Effect sensor is high enough to do this.

Comment: I'd also check that the magnetic field actually reduces enough during PWM low state. I doubt it, actually.

Comment: The inductance of your coil should change with object proximity. You could measure a change in dI/dt or priodically skip some PWM cycles to make a proper inductance measurement.